# Netlogo: moving turtles downhill to patches occupied by turtles with lower variables

Tags: netlogo

All my patches have a variable called "temperature" and I'm trying to move all the turtles downhill for temperature. But the turtles are also territorial, so there is a procedure called "social-all" that makes them move away from the turtle within their territory with the strongest "strength" variable.

I'm trying to combine the two, but I'm not sure what's the best way. Here's my code so far:

```
turtles-own  [
rivals
nearest-rival
strength
]

patches-own [temperature]

to go
ask turtles [
social-all
tick
end

to social-all ;;avoiding each other
find-rivals
if any? rivals with [strength >= [strength] of myself]
[find-nearest-rival
if (distance nearest-rival < minimum-territory) ;;a slider variable
[separate]]
end

to find-rivals
set rivals other turtles in-radius (minimum-territory - 1)
end

to find-nearest-rival
set nearest-rival min-one-of rivals [distance myself]
end

to get-cool
move-to patch-here
let p min-one-of neighbors [temperature]
if ([temperature] of p < temperature) ;; could add another if here?
[face p
move-to p]
end
```

I thought about putting another "if" in the "get-cool" procedure, maybe something like "if turtles here [strength] < [strength] myself." Would that work?

Comment: Once you can say exactly what you want to do in English, you will find it easier to say it in NetLogo.     (Separately: you don't need `move-to patch-here` in `get-cool`.)

Comment: Agree with Alan — it's hard to give you coding advice without a precise verbal description of exactly how you want the code to behave. You're suggesting adding some code to `get-cool`, but it seems like you've already got similar code in `social-all`, so I don't really get where you're going with this, or what exactly your question is. (Note that you can edit your question to clarify it.)